# Help to understand "because think it did the job" in the context

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> He added that if he were hired to make Boeing 777 disappear, he would “do the exact same thing”.
>
> “As far as I’m concerned, it’s very accurate flying **because think it
>   did the job** and we know, as a fact, that the military did not come
>   and intercept the aircraft,” he added.

The part I don't understand is **because think it did the job**. It doesn't look grammatical to me. What's *it* referring to? Can someone help me with it? Thanks!

Here is [the full source](https://www.yahoo.com/news/experts-think-theyve-finally-solved-mystery-disappeared-malaysian-airlines-flight-mh370-080029613.html).

Comment: The sentence looks like it's missing the word *we*: "...because **we** think it did the job."  The subject of *it* is probably the flying.

Comment: @stangdon it seems to me that "it did the job" is an idiomatic expression, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-the-job